# Why is my array getting passed as a 1d array

Tags: c, cs50

Even though the same thing is outputted twice when I look inside my debugger, "array" is a 2d array, and "arrayA" is a 1-dimensional array. How can I pass "array" into the function as a 2-dimensional array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void testCase (bool lockear[9][9]);
bool array[9][9];
int main(void)
{
   for(int i = 0; i > 3; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j > 3; j++)
       {
           array[i][j] = true;
       }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       {
           printf("%s ",array[i][j]?"true":"false");
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   testCase(array);
}
void testCase (bool arrayA[9][9])
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       {
           printf("%s ",arrayA[i][j]?"true":"false");
       }
       printf("\n");
   }



}
```

Comment: In C, (1d) arrays decay into pointers; 2d arrays decay into pointers to arrays. The argument passed to your function is of type `bool (*ArrayA)[9]`. Confused? Welcome to C programming!

Comment: What can I do to pass in the full 2d array?

Comment: Well, your function *is* getting access to the full array. Try adding a few `false` values into it, and you'll see them correctly in the function's output.

Comment: Note that your first nested for loop will run zero iterations since your continuation condition is `i > 3` and `i` is initialized to zero.

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers when passed as arguments. If you really want to copy the complete array as an argument, you need to put it in a `struct` and pass the instance of that `struct`. But I'm sure, you don't want that, because it needs a lot of processor cycles to copy and memory for the copy. If you just want to make sure that the called function does not change the original array, prepend `const` in the function's definition: `void testCase (const bool arrayA[9][9])`

Comment: @AdrianMole, arrays decay into pointers... a definition like `int a[]` is equivalent to `int *a`, but a definition `int a[9][9]` becomes `int (*a)[9]`, so the pointer arithmetic allows you to follow the array, row by row or element by element.  You are still capable of accesing the array using two subindices.

Comment: @Luis Other than the `int` *vs* `bool`, how is what you've said different from what I said the type of the argument was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(look at the note below, for some errors in your code)

Arrays are not passed to functions.  Arrays are passed as parameters by reference, so they don't change their morphology to be passed to a function.  As arrays cannot be passed by value, the compiler arranges to pass a reference, but as a reference, it is a pointer, it is said that they *decay into a pointer* on parameter declaration (despite you declare them as an array), this means that if you have a base type `T` for which you have an array (e.g. `T[9][9]`) the base element type of the array is `T elem[9]` (this is the base type of the whole array is itself an array of 9 `T` elements), and it is passed as a pointer (indeed as this thing: `T (*array_ref)[9]`) to the array.

In your case you have `bool array[9][9]`, and the type of the parameter when you declare it is `bool array[9][9]`, but the decay makes it to be actually `bool (*array)[9]`.  This can be easily tested by their `sizeof` operator application, with the following simple program shows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* the next macro prints a variable name and its sizeof */
#define P(_var) printf("sizeof "#_var" is %zd\n", sizeof _var)

void f(bool a[9][9])
{
    printf("in f()\n");
    P(a);       /* this will generate a warning because of the
                 * decay to pointer and will print the pointer
                 * size, instead, revealing the decay to pointer,
                 * besides the declaration of it as an array. */
    P(a[0]);
    P(a[0][0]);
}

int main()
{

    bool array[9][9];  /* this affects only parameters, not local variables */
    printf("in main()\n");
    P(array);   /* this will show the true array sizeof */
    P(array[0]);
    P(array[0][0]);
    f(array);
}
```

That will output (your system can show different numbers as, depending on the architecture, pointers can be 4 or 8 bytes long):

```
$ test_case
in main()
sizeof array is 81         <-- 9 x 9 bytes  == 81
sizeof array[0] is 9       <-- 9 booleans   == 9
sizeof array[0][0] is 1    <-- 1 boolean    == 1
in f()
sizeof a is 8              <-- pointer size == 8
sizeof a[0] is 9           <-- 9 booleans   == 9
sizeof a[0][0] is 1        <-- 1 boolean    == 1
$ _
```

By the way, 2D arrays are built one element after the other to form one row.... then one row is appended after the previous, until you have the complete array.  So it is easy to confound them with linear arrays, as the information about where a row ends and another starts is lost in the translation to machine language process.  You can see (but it it not encouraged) it as an array of arrays or as an array of 81 elements, one after the other.

### Note

Be careful as you have some typos (or errors) in your code, e.g. the test in the first loop says while `i > 3` and should be `i < 3` (`i` is initialized to `0`, so the loop will never get executed).  I have not checked further your code, but you should  test it before posting.  The inner loop has the same problem.

### Note 2

It is possible that the program gives you a warning informing you of the decay to pointer and that the `sizeof` operator will give you not the array size, but the pointer size.  This is expected (we are trying to illustrate the decay) and can be avoided by compiling with the following option: `-Wno-sizeof-array-argument`, but you can just ignore this warning (FreeBSD clang version 12.0.1).